Devexpress XRChart labels of y-axis overlaps
At the code below, the minValueY is 1 and maxValueY is 1,1. The elements in axisValuesY are from -1,0(included) to 1,0(included) and increases by 0,2. Now i see all the labels except for the label 1,0 which is under the topmost label 1,2. I am fine with 1,2 being topmost instead of 1,0 but I want 1,0 to appear on the y-axis as well. Instead there is an overlapped label texts in the place where 1,0 is supposed to be.
 var yAxis = diagram.AxisY;

 yAxis.WholeRange.Auto = false;
 yAxis.NumericScaleOptions.AutoGrid = false;

 maxValueY += (maxValueY - minValueY) * 0.05;

 yAxis.WholeRange.SetMinMaxValues(minValueY, maxValueY);

 diagram.AxisY.Label.ResolveOverlappingOptions.AllowHide = false;
 diagram.AxisY.Label.NumericOptions.Format = DevExpress.XtraCharts.NumericFormat.FixedPoint;
 diagram.AxisY.Label.NumericOptions.Precision = 1;


 List<string> axisValuesY = new List<string>();
 if (maxValueY - minValueY < 4)
 {
     axisValuesY.Clear();

     yAxis.NumericScaleOptions.GridSpacing = 0.2;
     yAxis.GridLines.Visible = true;

     for (double i = Math.Ceiling(minValueY / 0.2) * 0.2; i <= maxValueY; i += 0.2)
     {
         //if (i % 0.2 == 0)
             axisValuesY.Add(i.ToString("F1"));
     }

     diagram.AxisY.CustomLabels.Clear();
     foreach (string value in axisValuesY)
     {
         CustomAxisLabel customLabel = new CustomAxisLabel(value);
         diagram.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(customLabel);
     }               
 }

